# Did Jesus miraculously create a new set of clothes after he rose from the dead?

Tags: life-of-jesus, resurrection

The Bible narrates that after Jesus died on the cross then Joseph of Arimathea took his body down from the cross and wrapped it in a linen clothing. They then buried him inside a tomb but then after he rose from the dead, two disciples went to check and found the linen clothing that his body was wrapped in lying on the stone where his body laid.

## Burial of Jesus

Mathew 27:57-60

> When it was evening, there came a rich man from Arimathea, named Joseph, who also was a disciple of Jesus. He went to Pilate and asked for the body of Jesus. Then Pilate ordered it to be given to him. And Joseph took the body and wrapped it in a clean linen shroud and laid it in his own new tomb, which he had cut in the rock. And he rolled a great stone to the entrance of the tomb and went away. Mary Magdalene and the other Mary were there, sitting opposite the tomb.

The Gospels describe the resurrection  scene differently but according to the Gospel of Saint John the linen cloth was left there and the cloth that had covered the face of Jesus folded up in a place by itself.

## The Resurrection according to Saint John

John 20:6-7

> Then Simon Peter came, following him, and went into the tomb. He saw the linen cloths lying there, and the face cloth, which had been on Jesus' head, not lying with the linen cloths but folded up in a place by itself.

Since Jesus appeared to Mary and other disciples clothed, does it leave us to conclude that he miraculously created a new set of clothes to cover his resurrected body with?

Comment: Which do you think is more difficult - being resurrected from the dead or covering your body with new clothes?  Clothing the resurrected body would be a natural and logical thing to do.

Comment: I'm pretty confident there will be no Biblical or other historic document that can help us with this question.

Comment: @Lesley, yes because the book of Revelation clearly describes Jesus wearing a breastplate of gold and other clothing.

Comment: @Lesley, my question is why did Jesus think he didn't need the clothing he was buried with?

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Why is nobody mentioning that the angels came to Jesus after his resurrection and gave him a heavenly white robe, which represents immortality?

Comment: @JoshuaB, I think the angel who rolled the stone gave him new immortal clothes that's why he asked Mary not to touch her but only God has immortality and Jesus is Michael incarnate

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel - Amen to that, completely agree. Do you mind if we could share emails or something to have a discussion? Do you have reddit?

Comment: Thanks. I've become put out with the close-minded Trinitarian arrogance on this site.

Comment: Yes, I was also a trinitarian but today my eyes have been opened by the Bible itself. The angel of the lord is Michael aka Jesus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question does not appear to be answered in the Scriptures. The graveclothes were left there, it is true, and his raiment was previously parted among the Roman soldiers. It would not make sense to go around wearing graveclothes in His resurrected body, as He had previously commanded that Lazarus be loosed from his graveclothes and they would be symbolic of the bands of death, which He had broken. There is no evidence to suggest He took back His old clothing from His mortal life, either.

The question is, where did His clothes come from, post-resurrection?

For that matter, we could ask the same about those who came out of great tribulation, whom John saw in the Book of Revelation, wearing white robes:

> And one of the elders answered, saying unto me, What are these which are arrayed in white robes? and whence came they?
>
> And I said unto him, Sir, thou knowest. And he said to me, These are they which came out of great tribulation, and have washed their robes, and made them white in the blood of the Lamb. ([Revelation 7:13-14](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/rev/7.13-14?lang=eng))

Many of these will have died impoverished, perhaps not even having any robes of their own, let alone spotless and white ones. So where do they get their robes in the resurrection? *Who makes them?*

I think this is a good question that deserves its own time and attention. It calls to my mind another instance involving clothing and bringing back from the dead:

> Then Peter arose and went with them. When he was come, they brought him into the upper chamber: and all the widows stood by him weeping, and shewing the coats and garments which Dorcas made, while she was with them.
>
> But Peter put them all forth, and kneeled down, and prayed; and turning him to the body said, Tabitha, arise. And she opened her eyes: and when she saw Peter, she sat up. ([Acts 9:39-40](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/acts/9?lang=eng&id=39#p39))

If I may speculate for only a moment, the office of Tabitha is probably busy preparing to clothe in eternity all who come unto Christ. Certainly our repentance is necessary to weave the fabric of which our eternity is made. Is it miraculous that those who are diligent for the kingdom of Christ still get to contribute hereafter? I would submit that it is. (The fact that something is miraculous is not a license to take it for granted, but to the contrary, I have learned that **all things that are done, someone is the doer of them**. Therefore if you want something done, go and do it! "Six days shalt thou labor" doesn't expire in the resurrection. Work and glory continue, coupled with eternal rest. Angels aren't going to be twiddling their thumbs. They will be playing music, and using their talents.) The virtuous woman of Proverbs 31 is alive and well beyond the veil.

I can only surmise that there is a robe provided for each of the faithful out of the finest workmanship in eternity, or else perhaps they make their own. Angels are very industrious and resourceful beings, after all. Perhaps all we can do is ponder on the importance of clean, ample clothing even in eternity after the resurrection, since this is a very common symbol throughout the Scriptures of being made clean before God.

Some have suggested that the folded napkin may be a reference to a cultural custom conveying the sentiment "I will return". While perhaps we [can't fully justify](https://www.gotquestions.org/folded-napkin.html) the significance of that inference because the customs of the Jews and the Savior's intentionality behind it are not fully documented, it does seem like an enticing overlap with more modern cultures, and whether or not it seems a coincidence may be in the eye of the beholder.

To me the more basic observation is that no resurrected being goes around wearing his graveclothes. Having been graduated not only from mortal life but also from death, a proper upgrade is fitting.

Whatever the source, is it miraculous? Certainly. However, it symbolizes a far greater miracle, that through the Atonement of Christ, there will be any who will prevail in final judgment, being purified from all stain.
Nakedness is also used in Scripture as a metaphor for being exposed to sin by being unrepentant; these remain uncovered by the Savior's Atonement. The Hebrew word for Atonement, 'kaphar' literally means "to cover over", and represents being clothed adequately, an ordinance of family and kinship, of parent to child. Perhaps the Father made the covering for His Son.

At His return, He will be wearing blood red garments (Revelation 19:13).

"Miracle" or not, someone made them, and that is to me a miracle. Who exactly made them, I don't think I know enough to say, but it is in the Celestial family. What I am concerned about is the [quality of materials](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/media/video/2011-12-0040-because-he-came?lang=eng), the fiber of character and the purity of choices we make in this life, since those are the materials out of which our own clothing and abode in eternity -- if we have any to speak of -- will be made.

Comment: I like how you break down the problem and try to answer it with Biblical evidence. It is a white robe then that is automatically generated to cover the body of risen saints?

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel From what I have learned of God's plan, nothing is "automatic" independent of an intelligent agent. Everything that is done, someone has the joy of doing it. Based on Biblical descriptions of the faithful in this life and their joys in eternity, I imagine we will have someone to thank for the clothing we will wear in eternity, just as in this life we have someone to thank for the clothing that we wear. As noted above, clothing denotes a family relationship, is a symbol of atonement, and is an ordinance of the Lord's house, outlined in Exodus chapters 29, 40 & Matthew 22.

Comment: I am really happy that Jesus is alive and is sitted at the right hand of God and knows me by my name. How quick does time pass for those who are dead?

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Like a night's sleep! And then we shall hear the trumpets...

Comment: @JoshuaB, Amen. That disconnection from time is what will make it seem like a minute or a second. Then the arch-angel will shout with a loud voice and the dead shall hear it and come to the resurrection of life

Comment: “At that time Michael, the archangel who stands guard over your people, will arise. Then there will be a time of anguish greater than any since nations first came into existence. But at that time every one of your people whose name is written in the book will be RESCUED." (Daniel 12:1)

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Time passes slowly enough for those who are in the world of spirits that they get very, very antsy about our choices.
If only we would listen to the still, small voice, they might be able to get through to us about what matters most.

Answer (score 1):

**Did Jesus miraculously create a new set of clothes after he rose from the dead?**

The short answer is simply that we do not know!

The Scriptures do not allude to any clear answer to the question. But Scriptures may suggest an answer through deduction and speculation!

Did God create new clothes for the resurrected body of Christ? Possibly, but Scriptures are silent on this issue.

We know what happened to the clothing of Jesus when he was crucified.

> 23 When the soldiers crucified Jesus, they took his clothes, dividing them into four shares, one for each of them, with the undergarment remaining. This garment was seamless, woven in one piece from top to bottom.
>
> 24 “Let’s not tear it,” they said to one another. “Let’s decide by lot who will get it.”
>
> This happened that the scripture might be fulfilled that said,
>
> “They divided my clothes among them
> and cast lots for my garment.”
>
> So this is what the soldiers did.
>
> - [John 19:23-24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2019%3A23-24&version=NIV)

Some Christian traditions hold that the Seamless Robe of Jesus has been preserved to this; the most most popular tradition is that of Tiers. Thus either Jesus somehow was clothed in new clothes or something else.

> The Seamless Robe of Jesus (also known as the Holy Robe, Holy Tunic, Holy Coat, Honorable Robe, and Chiton of the Lord) is the robe said to have been worn by Jesus during or shortly before his crucifixion. Competing traditions claim that the robe has been preserved to the present day. One tradition places it in the Cathedral of Trier, another places it in Argenteuil's Basilique Saint-Denys, and several traditions claim that it is now in various Eastern Orthodox churches, notably Svetitskhoveli Cathedral in Mtskheta, Georgia.
>
> **Trier tradition**
>
> According to legend, Helena, mother of Constantine the Great, discovered the seamless robe in the Holy Land in the year 327 or 328 along with several other relics, including the True Cross. According to different versions of the story, she either bequeathed it or sent it to the city of Trier, where Constantine had lived for some years before becoming emperor. The monk Altmann of Hautvillers wrote in the 9th century that Helena was born in that city, though this report is strongly disputed by most modern historians.

> The history of the Trier robe is certain only from the 12th century, when Archbishop Johann I of Trier consecrated an altar which contained the seamless robe in early 1196. Although biographies of Johann I state that this was not the first time the robe was displayed, there are no historical dates or events presented which predate 1196. Sections of taffeta and silk have been added to the robe, and it was dipped in a rubber solution in the 19th century in an attempt to preserve it. The few remaining original sections are not suitable for carbon dating. The stigmatist Therese Neumann of Konnersreuth declared that the Trier robe was authentic.
>
> The relic is normally kept folded in a reliquary and cannot be directly viewed by the faithful. In 1512, during an Imperial Diet, Emperor Maximilian I demanded to see the Holy Robe which was kept in the Cathedral. Archbishop Richard von Greiffenklau arranged the opening of the altar that had enshrined the tunic since the building of the Dome and exhibited it. The people of Trier heard about that and demanded to see the Holy Robe. Subsequently, pilgrimages took place first annually, then every 7 years, in accordance with the Aachen pilgrimages. However, after 1545, pilgrimages where irregularly done due to warring in Europe. The pilgrimage occurrences are as follows: 1513, 1514, 1515, 1516, 1517, 1524, 1531, 1538, 1545, 1655, 1810, 1844, 1891, 1933, 1959, 1981, 1996, 2006, and 2012.
>
> [image]
>
> [Seamless robe of Jesus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seamless_robe_of_Jesus)

As I suggested above, either Jesus was miraculously clothed in new garments after his resurrection or another explication must be possible.

That possibility is that Christ’s body might have been clothed in a garment of light (God’s glory).

This possibility is not as far fetched as it seems on the surface, considering that there exists a tradition that both Adam and Eve were clothed in garments of light, prior to the falling into sin or original sin.
The tradition that both Adam and Eve wore garments of light can be found in [Jewish traditions](https://graceintorah.net/2015/09/08/garments-of-light-part-i/), the [writings of saints](https://biologos.org/series/genesis-creation-and-ancient-interpreters-in-the-garden/articles/genesis-creation-and-ancient-interpreters-in-the-garden) and the revelations of various [Christian Mystics](http://divinefiat.blogspot.com/2014/02/were-adam-and-eve-originally-clothed-in.html).

An interest noted can be gleaned from the story about the two disciples on the road to Emmaus. Their eyes were opened to the fact that it was Jesus that was speaking to them. Could Jesus be hiding the fact that his body was already clothed in a garment of light, just like that of Adam and Eve before their fall into sin. What our first parent lost through disobedience, Jesus restored through his sacrifice on the Cross!

> 30 When he was at the table with them, he took bread, gave thanks, broke it and began to give it to them. 31 Then their eyes were opened and they recognized him, and he disappeared from their sight. 32 They asked each other, “Were not our hearts burning within us while he talked with us on the road and opened the Scriptures to us?”
>
> 33 They got up and returned at once to Jerusalem. There they found the Eleven and those with them, assembled together 34 and saying, “It is true! The Lord has risen and has appeared to Simon.” 35 Then the two told what had happened on the way, and how Jesus was recognized by them when he broke the bread. - [Luke 24:13-35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2024%3A13-35&version=NIV)

Obviously Jesus hide something mysterious about himself with these two disciples.

Many are the mysteries in the Scriptures!

Comment: But wouldn't the disciples have told us that after he appeared onto them , he was radiating light from his body. For Mary to think that he was the gardener, Jesus must have been clothed like the gardener hence your answer needs revision

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Not necessarily. St. John has already stated that not all things are recorded in the Gospels.